# How to use multi touch feature of iphone remotely from desktop?

Tags: iphone, multi-touch, vnc, vnc-server

I am using veency on Iphone that is working as VNC server application. I have a .net client application that is working as VNC client to control Iphone from desktop.

How can I pass multi touch events to VNC server?

Answer (score 0):

I've been in touch with RealVNC support who say that as of today (03-Jul-2014) they do not have multi-touch support, but it is on their roadmap.